# object detection android opencv

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv

After taking a picture with an android phone I want to identify an object in the picture by clicking into it for example. Possible objects in most cases:
1. Ruler
2. Person
3. Pencil
I am using android prebuilt-opencv version 2.3.1 and I tried to click into the ruler object and floodfill it to mark it, but if the contours are not closed the whole picture will be filled.
a) I also tried to click into ruler object and go south, north, east, west to look where the edges are and collect these coordinates, but I ran into heavy problems there (don´t ask).

Questions:
1. Is it possible to close the contours somehow to just fill the wanted object?
2. What I ACTUALLY want to find are the coordinates of the bottom AND the height of (e.g.) the ruler.
ANY other solutions are appreciated. How would you realize it?

Update:I fixed the problem with a) and use this approach at the moment (not happy about it). I also tried Entreco ´s approach, but seem not to give the wanted solution by now.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you tried this, but usually, you can achieve better results by processing the image first.

1) Apply [GuassianBlur](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-gaussianblur) to remove the noise

2) Apply [AdaptiveThreshold](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-adaptivethreshold) -> to convert the image to black and white

3) Apply [Dilate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-dilate) operation, to fill the cracks

By using different settings for the AdaptiveThreshold and the Dilate operation, you might be able to get closed contours...

An example I used is like this:

```
// 1) Apply gaussian blur to remove noise
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGraySubmat, mIntermediateMat, new Size(11,11), 0);

// 2) AdaptiveThreshold -> classify as either black or white
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 2);

// 3) Invert the image -> so most of the image is black
Core.bitwise_not(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat);

// 4) Dilate -> fill the image using the MORPH_DILATE
Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, new Size(3,3), new Point(1,1));
Imgproc.dilate(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat, kernel);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @Entreco. I will try this and report.

Comment: @Entreco can we draw a rectangle arround the closed contours

Comment: it is  not detect  edge if black rectangle object.