# Image embossing in background of the Captured image

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to emboss a background image to the captured camera image.

i.e say i click a person's image in office, and pick the persons image and emboss it on the already existing hill background image,
So that the person's final image shows that he captured the image at hill side.

Can someone throw some idea on this or share code snippet to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite catch the embossing part even after reading the example. Image embossing is normally replacing each pixel of an image with a highlight or a shadow so the image area is raised to multiple levels having different depth.

But what you are asking is complex. If i am right, you want to merge the two images where the person from first image will be present in the hill side image.

The issue you will face here is object detection of a person in some random image. This is going to be really difficult. And moreover it will involve hardcore processing of the image with some math. At the end of the day, you do have to remember that what you are asking is for a mobile and not an desktop.

I suggest you to do some extensive research on object detection before proceeding with what you have in mind.

Here are some useful links

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_object_recognition

[object detection android opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786622/object-detection-android-opencv)

http://opencv.org/android
You can search SO for similar questions like this

Comment: Thanks for your Input karthick, yes I am trying to detect an object from one image and put it over to another image. Can you suggest any link or data for the same.

Comment: @Rah: Updated you can search in SO for similar questions. You will get some idea.